# Blender 2.83.0 suddenly begins crashing on startup with call to libc.8.so

Tags: error, command-line, linux

Blender version 2.83.0 has been running nicely on my system for several
months.  Suddenly a couple of days ago, it started crashing on startup just after a call to libc.so.6. I suspected an out of memory problem since all other versions of blender (various 2.7x versions) also quit working at the same time, and so I closed everything else running on my system. This action did not fix the problem for any version of Blender, so I suspected memory fragmentation, since my system stays up for a long time without being rebooted. After I rebooted all other versions of blender worked, only 2.83.0 kept failing. I haven't found a solution to this problem online other than the usual install new graphics drivers, etc. which don't seem to address my problem since the program had been running just fine.  I've looked for munged configuration or cache files but have not found any likely candidates. Moving the config files aside as one poster suggests did not fix the problem.  Any help would be appreciated.

System is an HP Pavilion A6109n;
graphics: VGA compatible controller:
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710 [Radeon HD 4350/4550];
OS is Fedora 31.
Blender is being run from the command line without any options

crash log:

````
# Blender 2.83.0, Commit date: 1970-01-01 00:00, Hash unknown

# backtrace
blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x37) [0x55d78fa6ea27]
blender(+0xcff2ba) [0x55d78d7042ba]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x3c6b0) [0x7f74bb93a6b0]
blender(GPU_draw_list_command_add+0x5f) [0x55d78f94891f]
blender(+0x10bcb2d) [0x55d78dac1b2d]
blender(+0x10be0b7) [0x55d78dac30b7]
blender(+0x10e8264) [0x55d78daed264]
blender(+0x10b5b3e) [0x55d78dabab3e]
blender(DRW_draw_render_loop_ex+0x2f0) [0x55d78dabae60]
blender(view3d_main_region_draw+0x93) [0x55d78e14af63]
blender(ED_region_do_draw+0x851) [0x55d78dd22221]
blender(wm_draw_update+0x4ba) [0x55d78d9d4c3a]
blender(WM_main+0x30) [0x55d78d9d2b90]
blender(main+0x321) [0x55d78d6d6821]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f74bb9251a3]
blender(_start+0x2e) [0x55d78d7006ae]
```
````

Comment: Never mind. Version 2.83.1 works on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved by verion 2.83.1